# why should I use bind(this) with a method in a class?

Tags: javascript

Given the documentation

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

I'm currently following a tutorial about creating a blockchain using node.js

https://developers.caffeina.com/chiccocoin-learn-what-is-a-blockchain-by-creating-one-in-nodejs-12929a89208b

But what I don't understand in the following example (code provide by the tutorial I'm following) is why should I bind the keyword '**this**' to a method which belong to a class. Given the function **newBlock()** belong of the class **Blockchain**, it should have access to the '**this**' and all of the variable related to the class **Blockchain**.

```
class Blockchain {
  constructor () {
    this.chain = []
    this.newBlock = this.newBlock.bind(this)
    this.newBlock(100, 1)
  }
  newBlock (proof, previousHash) {
    const block = this.chain.length + 1
  }
}
```

Does anyone can explain me why should I use **bind(this**) with a method in a class ? Actually it may be possible that I misunderstood the purpose of **bind(this)** so that would be great if you could point me out what did I misunderstand.

Thanks :)

Comment: there is a functional demo on [the MDN page for `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) right underneath the text you quoted, and there is another section titled "Examples"; both of these in my opinion describe quite well how and why to use `bind`.  What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Before down voting my question wait a minute. I'm following a tutorial about creating a blockchain  using node.js https://developers.caffeina.com/chiccocoin-learn-what-is-a-blockchain-by-creating-one-in-nodejs-12929a89208b and the author use bind(this) in his example. That's why I ask on SO. The code doesn't belong to me. I just remove 90% of the code to make it easier to understand

Comment: In this context, it's useless. But maybe it is used elsewhere like, for example, an event listener where `this` get assigned something else so `this` is not the instance of the class and to make sure it will be the instance of the class we use `bind`

Comment: What do you mean by 'this get assigned something else' ?

Comment: @S7_0 For example: `addEventListener("click", instance.newBlock);` => `this` inside `newBlock` will be the element that fired the event, not `instance`. Using `bind` will make `this` inside `newBlock` always be `instance`. This is a brower example, but it applies to nodejs too (most of the time).

Comment: Quite possible author wrote it just as a habit. Not always easy to assess why an author wrote something the way they did when it may also be redundant as in this case

Answer (score 2):

Bind will create a copy of the function which will guarantee that the reference of "this" in function newBlock will point to Blockchain. If a new function (let's call it function readBlocks) were to invoke newBlock, it's this context would instead point to readBlocks instead of Blockchain. Binding will allow you to use newBlock without worrying about it's this context being dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

class definition the way you did, in javascript, is still doing prototypal inheritence behind the scenes. This class definition is malleable and you can add more methods to it by just adding more methods to it's prototype. So the `class` syntax is more like syntactic sugar (not completely, but for most practical purposes) for the normal prototypal inheritence done using functions.

Given that background, `this` binding in javascript was always done at runtime (except for arrow functions). The context in which a particular method is called determines the `this` binding. It's not bound at the time of defining the method. But that rule does not hold if you prebind the method to a particular context, like you did in your example with `.bind`.

If you had not done that, someone could have called the method newBlock like this

```
let a = new Blockchain()
let b = new Blockchain()

a.newBlock.call(b, proof, previousHash)
```

And since binding of this is done at runtime, in the above case, the method newBlock will be called with `this` refering to object `b`. But that will not happen if you prebind the method using `.bind`.

It's tricky. But main takeaway is that the runtime binding rules of `this` in javascript still hold for the new class syntax. Hope it helped.